# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null

Tags: php, laravel

Hi Im encountering fatal error on this and i cant find out any solutions here,

this is the error it returns when this function is called.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null

$startDate = $data->started_at ? \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data->started_at) : null;

    return $data ? (object) [
        'planId' => $data->plan_id ?? '',
        'comment' => $data->comment ?? '',
        'facilitator' => $data->facilitator ?? '',
        'date' => $startDate->format('d/m/Y') ?? '',
        'time' => $startDate->format('H:i:s') ?? '',

    ] : (object) [];
}
```

additional Info,

I am trying to retrieve data on this, however in this case I have no **startDate** and still would like to return the data that was save. Im not sure if my syntax is right.

Thanks Lads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `$startDate` can sometimes be null, you need to check if it's null before calling `format()` on it, since you can't call a method on a null value.

If you're using PHP 8.0, you can combine null-safe operators (`?->`) with your existing null-coalescing operators (`??`):

```
'date' => $startDate?->format('d/m/Y') ?? '',
'time' => $startDate?->format('H:i:s') ?? ''
```

Otherwise you can use ternary operators (`? :`):

```
'date' => $startDate === null ? '' : $startDate->format('d/m/Y'),
'time' => $startDate === null ? '' : $startDate->format('H:i:s')
```

Comment: or call laravel helper function `optional`. as in `optional($startDate)->format('d/m/Y')`